# How to rewrite mysql constraints syntax?

Tags: mysql, constraints

I need to add a check constraint on mysql using phpmyadmin

I have a table
`wp_nrOrevePerPunetore` with 3 colums `ID` , `start_date` and `end_date`

this works fine

```
alter table wp_nrOrevePerPunetore add constraint conEnddtbiggerThanStartDt check(end_date < '2030-01-01' );
```

but this

```
alter table wp_nrOrevePerPunetore add constraint conEnddtbiggerThanStartDtt 
check(end_date > start_date );
```

throws this error:

> Static analysis: 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the
> previous one. (near "check" at position 79)

What would be the right syntax for the second constraint to get executed?

ps: both start_date and end_date are datetime type

Comment: So what is the reason for not working on phpmyadmin??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpMyAdmin attempts to do syntax validation of your SQL statements, but it has fallen behind and does not recognize valid syntax in newer versions of MySQL. I viewed the [changelog for phpMyAdmin](http://phpmyadmin.sourceforge.net/documentation/changelog.php), but I don't see any mention that they have added support for check constraints.

So this is not a problem with MySQL Server, it's a problem with phpMyAdmin. See this open feature request: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13592

It's pretty disappointing that MySQL has supported CHECK constraints since 8.0.16 (2019-04-25), but phpMyAdmin hasn't included support for that syntax. But phpMyAdmin is an open-source project with only two individual programmers doing most of the work, so progress is slow.

One comment on that issue report says:

> Right now, you can add the CHECK constraint with a custom SQL statement. Even though the parser indicates a syntax error, it works.

You can also apply check constraints if you use the command-line MySQL client, not phpMyAdmin.